# ResEdit resource editor in Windows suddenly closes its window after launch and cannot find windows.h

Tags: windows, resources

I have not been able to solve the problem for a week! Help me please!
For several years I have been working with ResEdit on CodeBlocks in Windows without any problems at all.
I suppose this problem occurred after I reinstalled CodeBlocks to a newer 32 bit version with MinGW compiler at work and at home (I need to get 32 ​​bit programs).
ResEdit resource editor in Windows suddenly closes the window after launch and cannot find the files specified in the directive #include such as windows.h. Sometimes it lets me do a little work, and then suddenly closes. This happens at home on the 64-bit version of Windows 10 and ResEdit, and at work on the 32-bit version of Windows 7 and ResEdit.
I tried to specify the paths to the include folder where there is windows.h in the PATH variable, in the program itself, and in the ResEdit.xml file. I tried to specify the paths to windows.h, which is in CodeBlocks MinGW folder, and in the separately installed MinGW compiler:

C: \ Program Files (x86) \ CodeBlocks \ MinGW \ i686-w64-mingw32 \ include

C: \ MinGW \ include

All without success.
The worst thing is that I can't get other resource editors to work with my RC file, such as ResourceEditor, XN ResourceEditor, Resource Hacker.
My RC script is:

```
// Generated by ResEdit 1.6.6
// Copyright (C) 2006-2015
// http://www.resedit.net

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"

//
// Bitmap resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDB_BITMAP1        BITMAP         ".\\ColorRamp.bmp"



//
// Dialog resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
DLG_MAIN DIALOG 0, 0, 850, 450
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_SETFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Voltammograph"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    PUSHBUTTON      "CopyV", ID_OCV, 811, 381, 26, 14, BS_CENTER, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "Copy values", 0, 88, 349, 111, 78, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Time (ms)", 0, 96, 376, 31, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "Copy", ID_BUTTON_COPY, 142, 405, 42, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "Save", ID_BUTTON_SAVE, 683, 374, 38, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_COMPONENT_N, 27, 386, 48, 13, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_COMPONENT_N, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 63, 386, 11, 14, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "First", 0, 7, 388, 14, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "Indicators", 0, 683, 391, 93, 45, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "PCA", 0, 4294967295, 374, 84, 77, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "Controls", 0, 1, 324, 850, 127, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Filter", IDD_FILTER2, 3, 348, 78, 11, BS_LEFTTEXT, WS_EX_STATICEDGE
    LTEXT           "Jump length", 0, 411, 337, 39, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_JUMP_LENGTH, 458, 334, 49, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_JUMP_LENGTH, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 495, 334, 11, 15, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_FILE_NAME, 47, 332, 354, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "About", IDABOUT, 819, 421, 28, 14, BS_CENTER, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "", 0, 427, 428, 8, 1, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Start number", 0, 410, 354, 41, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_START_N, 458, 350, 49, 15, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_START_N, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 495, 350, 11, 15, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_SCALE, 458, 366, 49, 15, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_SCALE, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 495, 366, 11, 15, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Scale 1-100 %", 0, 410, 370, 46, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_COLOR_MAX, 458, 383, 48, 15, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_COLOR_MAX, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 494, 383, 11, 16, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Color maximum", 0, 410, 386, 48, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Scan point", 0, 410, 434, 35, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT5, 457, 431, 47, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_Y, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 493, 431, 11, 14, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Autoscale", IDD_AUTO, 3, 361, 78, 13, BS_LEFTTEXT, WS_EX_STATICEDGE
    LTEXT           "Subtrahend N", 0, 410, 403, 45, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT4, 458, 400, 47, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPIN_SUBTRAHEND, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 493, 400, 11, 14, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT3, 457, 416, 48, 13, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_X, UPDOWN_CLASS, WS_TABSTOP | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 493, 416, 11, 12, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT2, 727, 418, 42, 13, ES_READONLY, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "Open *.muh", ID_OPEN, 3, 332, 43, 14, BS_CENTER, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel", IDCANCEL, 817, 436, 32, 14, BS_CENTER, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1, 727, 401, 42, 13, ES_READONLY, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Voltage", IDC_STATICTEXT1, 689, 405, 25, 9, NOT WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Scan number", IDC_STATICTEXT3, 410, 417, 43, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Current", IDC_STATICTEXT2, 690, 422, 24, 9, NOT WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "End", 0, 7, 403, 14, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_COMPONENT_END, 27, 401, 48, 13, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", IDC_SPINCONTROL_COMPONENT_END, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 63, 401, 11, 14, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_TIME, 142, 373, 42, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "PCA", IDD_PCA, 8, 418, 67, 11, BS_LEFTTEXT, WS_EX_STATICEDGE
    PUSHBUTTON      "Delete PC", ID_BUTTON_DELETE, 7, 433, 70, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "FFT", ID_BUTTON_FFT, 723, 374, 37, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "Plot", ID_BUTTON_PLOT, 763, 374, 31, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_PERIOD, 142, 357, 42, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_NUMBER, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Period (ms)", 0, 96, 361, 36, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "N of scans", 0, 96, 392, 35, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_N_OF_SCANS, 142, 389, 42, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
}



//
// Manifest resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
1                  RT_MANIFEST    ".\\manifest.xml"
```

I intalled Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and specified the path to the folder with the file Windows.h in the PATH variable and in the ResEdit.xml file. But that didn't solve the problem. First time after that it works. Than I tried to run ResEdit from CodeBlocks. It opens and closes few seconds later. When I ran the application again on its own, it also closed. :(

Answer (score 1):

A couple more days and I found the answer myself.
It turns out that you just need to uncheck the "Auto check updates" checkbox in the Preferences. This is understandable, because the website of ResEdit is currently not available.
To prevent the program window from closing, you need to open the ResEdit.xml file and delete the include tags.[See the picture]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0yAH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the file "ResEdit.xml" for the line `"<autoCheckUpdate value="true " />"` and replace it with `"<autoCheckUpdate value="false " />"`

Comment: I've edited your answer because it was unreadable (code needs to be fenced). Once done, I seem to notice that it's the same solution as Valery's answer, isn't it?

Comment: This is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

ResEdit requirs `windows.h` file
The settings dialog offering to dowmload Microsoft Windows SDK and .NET Framework 4
[image]

Unfortunately this link doesn't work. So you may visit the Microsoft offcial site and find Microsoft Windows SDK and .NET Framework 4. I used Windows SDK (10.0.22621) from here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

I used a default path for setup and after that I added `windows.h` path:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\
```

In my ResEdit settings I have three pathes:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\
```

It working well